# How do I use Ext JS together with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I'm a newbie in Ext JS. I would like to know. How can I use Ext JS, together with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Visual Studio 2015? I mean, what files I need to add in ASP.NET MVC project to get access to Ext JS 6. I want to split my application into two parts Front-end project with Sencha ExtJS and the back-end with  ASP.Net Web API. But I do not understand how to combine Ext JS 6 with Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET MVC Project. So I could run Front-end project with Sencha ExtJS from Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't ExtJS have a website with documentation?

Comment: Everywhere are advised to use Sencha Cmd for initial generation of the project. But I think this approach is a lot of garbage if I connect this project to the Visual Studio. I would like to simply connect some files to Visual Studio project but I can't find  the necessary files

Comment: Use Ext.NET http://ext.net/

Comment: As I understand Ext.NET does not support all components of Ext JS

Comment: I usually create an empty web application in Visual Studio, then i use sencha cmd to generate the app in the proper folder of the empty web application.  Then in visual studio i show hidden files in explorer and add the ones i need for the extjs app into the project.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard rumors that Sencha is working on a Visual Studio plugin...

...but until that gets released, I wrote a [blog post](http://www.akawebdesign.com/2014/01/29/sencha-asp-net-mvc-visual-studio-2012/) about this topic a while back. My post might be a bit outdated (using older versions of the framework, Cmd) but it should point you in the right direction.